# Setting default initial values for select multiple component

Tags: antd

Using the select component i am having a hard time trying to set initial values.
As the docs. says im suppose to fill in the value prop with only string|number|string[]|number[].
Now the problem with this is that i need to show text on the input and send an id value on submit, but with this you show the same value you send.

```
<Select
        mode="multiple"
        defaultValue={tags} // => would need something like tags = [{id: 1, name: "Science"}]
        placeholder="Select tags"
        onSearch={this.fetchTags}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
      >
        {tags.map(tag => <Option value={tag.id} key={tag.id}>{tag.name}</Option>)}
      </Select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So "labelInValue" is what i really needed in case anyone else experience the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `value` instead of `defaulValue`. Here is a sample code from my project:

```
const stateTasksOptions =
    this.tasksStore.filters.init.state.map(item =>
        <Select.Option key={item.id} value={item.id} title={<span className={`${item.id}Label`}>{item.title}</span>}>
            <span className={`${item.id}Label`}>{item.title}</span> - <span class="normal-text">{item.help}</span>
        </Select.Option>
    )

return (
    ....
    <Select
        mode="multiple"
        value={this.tasksStore.filters.selected.state.map(d => d)}
        onChange={this.handleTasksStatus}
        optionLabelProp="title"
    >
        {stateTasksOptions}
    </Select>
    ....
)
```

And some css for colorizing.

**Result**:
[image]

`this.tasksStore.filters.init.state` looks like:

```
state = [
    {id: "done", title: "Исполнена", help: "исполнены после 24.04.2017"},
    {id: "active", title: "В работе", help: "текущие задачи"},
    {id: "planned", title: "Запланирована", help: "задачи на будущее"},
    {id: "missed", title: "Просрочена", help: "срок исполнения истек"},
    {id: "archived", title: "Архив", help: "выполнены ранее 24.04.2017"}
]
```

Comment: It isn't what it was asked in the main question, but it really helped me a lot.. i have just thrown away a few hours trying with "defaulValue". Thanks a lot